# iPhone : Unable to find following screen in in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am unable to find following screen in the in-app purchase.

Do I need to approve my app for in-app purchase ?

Below screen is from the iTunesConnectHelp.pdf
[image]

Whereas I am getting following screen in itunes connect.

So I am unable to make my inapp purchase's `submit for review`.

Where do I navigate to get the `Submit for Review` option?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you read the notice in your screenshoot?

"The first In-App Purchase for an app ..."

So, try first to submit your app!

Comment: I have already submitted app but still i am not getting that option.

Comment: by submit you mean : `Waiting for Upload` or `Waiting for review` ?

Answer (score 0):

With your in-app purchase added to the list, Reject you actual binary if any, then click on ready to upload, then upload you binary and that should start the review process. let me know if you need further help!

Comment: I have already uploaded binary but it is also asking for ready to upload for in-app purchase. Where I am unable to find `Submit for Review` option.